# ArcGIS: Create Feature from Coordinate Array

Tags: gis, arcgis

I'm trying to use the [Bing Isochrone API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt814919.aspx) to create a feature in ArcGIS...

For now, I have a coordinate array defining a polygon - roughly like [[32.19802, -97.09152],[32.17197, -97.05196],[32.16111, -97.02786],[32.1298, -97.01473],...etc.]

I'd like to take that collection of coordinates and turn it into a feature in ArcGIS... But I'm new enough to this that I'm not sure how to go about it.

If it helps, I'd actually like to provide multiple polygon arrays and use them to create multiple features. I could put the coordinate arrays into a table or something if that would help.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

ArcMap has an option to import X,Y Coordinates, and to convert them into a shape file. Check this link for more info on how to do it : https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000012745